# Oct 2022: banks with low, or no ATM fee in Chile

Tags: international-travel, budget, chile

Several  years ago, it was reported that Banco International and  Banco Bice in Santiago weren't charging ATM fees. Apparently that's no longer the case, at least with Banco International.

As an American tourist travelling to Chile, I am interested in learning about Chilean banks with low, or possibly not charging any, ATM fees, mainly Santiago. Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Midavalo the question is stated fairly clearly, even if it doesn't have a question mark at the end as written: "I am interested in learning about Chilean banks with low, or possibly not charging any, ATM fees, mainly Santiago."

Comment: When living in Rancagua till 2016, I tried to maintain a list of fees at ATMs I found around town (they all had fees), at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/58504/36998, but haven't returned except a brief visit in 2018 when I couldn't do much checking. I was also rarely in Santiago so couldn't check the (apparently not common) Banco Security or Banco Internacional locations other folks mentioned. My best advice, given how hard they'll be to avoid with most ATMs/banks you'll find, is to open something like a Charles Schwab checking account, which should refund them, and use that while there.

Answer (score 2):

Good luck.

A three-year old [web page](https://asocialnomad.com/chile/atm-fees-chile/) claims that Banco Internacional ATMs were free. I was in Santiago, Chile at about that time, but I couldn’t persuade my family to get off one Metro stop early to test. Our bank refunds us these fees, so I am less careful than I used to be.